# Is there a way to easily translate robot framework html test files to robot test files?

Tags: robotframework, translation

I was wondering if there is some tool created or some robot framework internal function that can translate my html test files into robot test files

I was only looking up robot documentation but couldn't find anything alike

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open those old test files in [RIDE](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) and save in .robot (txt) format.

(If there is no direct way, then you can copy from Text Editor and paste in another text editor.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should be able to use old version of Robot Framework, and use the built-in Tidy tool to read up the .html and output .robot files. But you will need a little bit more work anyway, because of some backwards incompatible syntax changes between then (when HTML was supported, and when Tidy was part of official distribution) and now (when there's a new parser without HTML support, and Tidy had been dropped in favor of external robotframework-tidy).